# Responsive content in iframe is not responsive on iPad

Tags: ipad, iframe

I have a responsive site, but when loaded into an iframe, the site is not responsive anymore on iPad, while working well on PC and Mac. The iframe has 100% width but still shows an horizontal scrolling on iPad, while working on all PC and Mac browsers.

http://www.genovaperte.it/item/hostaia-del-missionario/web

Comment: I discovered that specifying fixed width for the iframe fixes the problem. But when I put width=100% it shows the problem. I need variable width.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the framed site itself.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K64Mm/6/
Working example with a "good" responsive site: http://www.genovaperte.it/item/ristorante-zeffirino/web

```
    </div> 
    <div class="content">
        <iframe scrolling="yes" src="http://www.zeffirino.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

.wrapper { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-bottom: 45px; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
.top { height: 45px; background-color: red; }
.content { height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: auto !important; }
.content iframe { display: block; border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution >> iframe + jquery and work like a charm. jsfiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/leowebdev/6NSX3/

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
      html body {width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;overflow: hidden;font-family: arial;font-size: 10px;color: #6e6e6e;background-color: #000;} #preview-frame {width: 100%;background-color: #fff;}</style>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var calcHeight = function() {
           $('#preview-frame').height($(window).height());
         }

         $(document).ready(function() {
           calcHeight();
         }); 

         $(window).resize(function() {
           calcHeight();
         }).load(function() {
           calcHeight();
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe id="preview-frame" src="http://yourwebsitehere.com/" name="preview-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
      </iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```